# AngularJS controller for a tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, ng-controller

I have three tabs in my page. I'm using `tabset` and `tab` according to [Angular Bootstrap Docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs).

I set a controller for the `<div>` which has the `tabset`as

```
<div ng-controller="Tabs" class="panel panel-default" id="tabs-panel"> 
  <tabset  class="panel-body">
    <tab heading="Tab 1"> </tab>
    <tab heading="Tab 2"> </tab>
    <tab heading="Tab 3"> </tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

The corresponding page is [image]

But, when I try to add another controller for my 2nd tab as

```
<div ng-controller="Tabs" class="panel panel-default" id="tabs-panel"> 
  <tabset  class="panel-body">
    <tab heading="Tab 1"> </tab>
    <tab heading="Tab 2" ng-controller="Tab2> </tab>
    <tab heading="Tab 3"> </tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

[image]

I now find that the heading is not displayed and I can no longer click the Tab2.

Why is that? How to get back the same functionality?

Is this the right way to add another controller in an existing controller?

My **app.js** :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('Tabs', function ($scope) {

});


myApp.controller('Tab2', function ($scope) {

});
```

Comment: Why would you want separate controllers for each tab?

Comment: I'm very new to angular and each tab of mine has different functions. So, I thought it is nice to have a controller for each tab.

Comment: I think unless you have a massive amount of functionality in each tab (in which case I would consider using a directive for the content), there is no need for separate controllers, you are just complicating it.

Comment: Moreover, each tab has almost same functionality, so using same ng-model might rise in namespace conflict.

Comment: What directive would you suggest? A new module for each tab?

Comment: A directive in general, not "which". By the way it sounds I would just use 1 controller though, name spacing aside. Like if you had a ton of logic or dom manipulation or whatever, make your own directive for the content of each tab (which will have it's own controller).

Comment: Okay! As far as I know directives can be anything - controllers, modules, models etc. So, what is that you want me to use?

Comment: I'm not saying necesarily to use it, but if you really want to separate your logic it is a good way to do it. You could have tab1 directive, tab2 directive and so on. But honestly, if you don't have that much content/functionality in each tab just use 1 controller...

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm pretty sure this problem is introduced by Angular 1.4.x. 1.3.x allows a controller for each tab. Initially I thought the problem was introduced by the new version of UI Bootstrap. After exclusive tests, I found the latest(0.14.3) version of UI Bootstrap works well with Angular 1.3.20.

Comment: @ajmajmajma does having separate controllers for each tab have any problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are at least three ways you could organize your controller code:

1. Everything in one `TabController`
2. Custom directive for each tab
3. Add your tab logic to the tab callback function.

Please have a look at the demo below or here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/8u55wea9/).

It's the [`ui-bootstrap`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) example code with the above mentioned points added.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('TabsDemoCtrl', TabsController)
    .directive('sepecialTab', SpecialTab);

function TabsController($scope, $window) {
    $scope.tabs = [{
        title: 'Dynamic Title 1',
        content: 'Dynamic content 1'
    }, {
        title: 'Dynamic Title 2',
        content: 'Dynamic content 2',
        disabled: true
    }];

    $scope.alertMe = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
        });
    };

    $scope.thirdTabCallback = function () {
        $scope.test = 'I\'m the third tab callback';

        $scope.clickme = function () {
            $window.alert('third tab only function');
        };
    };
}

function SpecialTab() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log('Special tab ctrl, runs on start.');
            $scope.hello = 'hello from special tab controller';
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.1/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
    <p>Select a tab by setting active binding to true:</p>
    <p>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[0].active = true">Select second tab</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[1].active = true">Select third tab</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[1].disabled = ! tabs[1].disabled">Enable / Disable third tab</button>
    </p>
    <hr />
    <tabset>
        <tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
        <tab heading="Static title 2" sepecial-tab="">Static content2 {{hello}}</tab>
        <tab heading="Static title 3" select="thirdTabCallback()">Static content3 {{test}}
            <button ng-click="clickme()">click me</button>
        </tab>
        <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">{{tab.content}}</tab>
        <tab select="alertMe()">
            <tab-heading> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!</tab-heading>I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!</tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay! But why can't I add another controller, like I did in my question. The example you cited is the same one which I used to make my code.

Comment: `Angular-ui tab` and `ng-controller` directives are requesting an isolated scope on the same element and that's not working ([error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=capital&p1=country&p2=new%2Fisolated%20scope&p3=%3Cdiv%20country%3D%22Russia%22%20capital%3D%22Moscow%22%3E) in the console). But you could fix that by adding the `ng-controller` to a `<div/>` tag inside the tab. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/8u55wea9/2/) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Here a custom directive to use in tabs, so I can use custom controllers for each tab.

```js
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .directive('tabController', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: '@',
      name: 'tabController',
    }
  })
  .controller('MyCustomController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = "Hey, I am The first controller";
  })
  .controller('MyCustomController2', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = "Hey, I am the second controller!";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<html>

<div ng-app="myModule">


  <uib-tabset type="tabs">
    <uib-tab tab-controller="MyCustomController as ctrl">
      <uib-tab-heading>
        <span ng-bind="ctrl.title"></span>
      </uib-tab-heading>
      <p ng-bind="ctrl.title"></p>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab tab-controller="MyCustomController2 as ctrl2">
      <uib-tab-heading>
        <span ng-bind="ctrl2.title"></span>
      </uib-tab-heading>
      <p ng-bind="ctrl2.title"></p>
    </uib-tab>

  </uib-tabset>

</div>
```